# number of spanning trees in a graph...

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have difficulties with the following. We prooved the matrix-tree-theorem, and as I understand it should be useful here, but still...somehow I can't put the details together...the problem is as follows...

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and denote by $t(G)$ the number of different spanning trees of $G$. Furthermore, construct graph $G'$ by replacing one of it's edges by (i) $n$ parallel edges and (ii) by a path of length 2.

Describe $t(G')$ in relation to $t(G)$, $t(G-e)$, and $t(G/e)$ for both situations (i) and (ii).
[I guess what is meant here is express $t(G')$ by using  $t(G)$, $t(G-e)$, and $t(G/e)$, the last one being the graph $G$ contracted on edge $e$.]

Always so thankful for your help.. :)

Comment: Hint: consider the two mutually exclusive cases of whether the edge appears in the tree or not. You can do this from first principles, without relying on the matrix-tree theorem.

Comment: Is it for (i) just $t(G') = t(G-e) + n \cdot t(G/e)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.